# When does alpha-beta search with memory return cutoff values?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, chess, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I have implemented an alpha beta search with transposition table.

Do I have the right ideas here about storing cutoffs in the table?

**Specifically, is my scheme for returning the cutoffs when a table hit occurs correct?** (And likewise, storing them.) My implementation seems to conflict with [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax#Negamax_with_alpha_beta_pruning_and_transposition_tables), yet it intuitively seems correct to me.

**Also, my algorithm never stores an entry with the at_most flag. When should I be storing these entries?**

Here is my (simplified) code demonstrating the main ideas:

```cc
int ab(board *b, int alpha, int beta, int ply) {
    evaluation *stored = tt_get(b);
    if (entryExists(stored) && stored->depth >= ply) {
        if (stored->type == at_least) { // lower-bound
            if (stored->score >= beta) return beta;
        } else if (stored->type == at_most) { // upper bound
            if (stored->score <= alpha) return alpha;
        } else { // exact
            if (stored->score >= beta) return beta; // respect fail-hard cutoff
            if (stored->score < alpha) return alpha; // alpha cutoff
            return stored->score;
        }
    }   

    if (ply == 0) return quiesce(b, alpha, beta, ply);

    int num_children = 0;
    move chosen_move = no_move;
    move *moves = board_moves(b, &num_children);

    int localbest = NEG_INFINITY;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_children; i++) {
        apply(b, moves[i]);
        int score = -ab(b, -beta, -alpha, ply - 1);
        unapply(b, moves[i]);
        if (score >= beta) {
            tt_put(b, (evaluation){moves[i], score, at_least, ply});
            return beta; // fail-hard
        }
        if (score >= localbest) {
            localbest = score;
            chosen_move = moves[i];
            if (score > alpha) alpha = score;
        }
    }
    tt_put(b, (evaluation){chosen_move, alpha, exact, ply});
    return alpha;
}
```

Comment: *I think there is a bug* - not a good question. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Idos Fair enough. I have edited the question -- I'm not having a specific problem, but want to check that I have the right ideas about this complicated algorithm.

Comment: Also, not appropriate here. It is very vague and broad. If you don't actually **have** a problem that you can point to, then this is off-topic, sorry...

Comment: @Idos Edited again with a specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My implementation seems to conflict with this one

The code for transposition table look up seems right to me. It's roughly equivalent to that on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax#Negamax_with_alpha_beta_pruning_and_transposition_tables).

```cc
// Code on Wikipedia rewritten using your notation / variable names
if (entryExists(stored) && stored->depth >= ply)
{
  if (stored->type == at_least)
    alpha = max(alpha, stored->score);
  else if (stored->type == at_most)
    beta = min(beta, stored->score);
  else if (stored->type == exact)
    return stored->score;

  if (alpha >= beta)
    return stored->score;
}
```

That is equivalent to (the check `if (alpha >= beta)` has been moved inside each node type):

```cc
if (entryExists(stored) && stored->depth >= ply)
{
  if (stored->type == at_least)
  {
    alpha = max(alpha, stored->score);
    if (alpha >= beta)  return stored->score;
  }
  else if (stored->type == at_most)
  {
    beta = min(beta, stored->score);
    if (alpha >= beta)  return stored->score;
  }
  else if (stored->type == exact)
    return stored->score;
}
```

and this can be changed in:

```cc
if (entryExists(stored) && stored->depth >= ply)
{
  if (stored->type == at_least)
  {
    // if (max(alpha, stored->score) >= beta) ...
    if (stored->score >= beta)  return stored->score;
  }
  else if (stored->type == at_most)
  {
    // if (min(beta, stored->score) <= alpha) ...
    if (stored->score <= alpha)  return stored->score;
  }
  else if (stored->type == exact)
    return stored->score;
}
```

The remaining difference is that Wikipedia uses a [fail-soft](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Fail-Soft) optimization, while your code is the classic alpha-beta pruning ([fail-hard](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Fail-Hard)). Fail-soft is a small improvement but doesn't change the key points of the algorithms.

---

> my algorithm never stores an entry with the at_most flag. When should I be storing these entries?

There is a bug in how you store the `exact` / `at_most` node type. Here you're assuming that the node is always of type `exact`:

```cc
tt_put(b, (evaluation){chosen_move, alpha, exact, ply});
```

actually it can be an `at_most` node:

```cc
if (alpha <= initial_alpha)
{
  // Here we haven't a best move.
  tt_put(b, (evaluation){no_move, initial_alpha, at_most, ply});
}
else
   tt_put(b, (evaluation){chosen_move, alpha, exact, ply});
```